# Unable to understand python reversed function

Tags: python, variables

Why list is used while printing? Without using list why can't we just print the reverse string?

My code:

```py
name = "prajwal"
name1 = reversed(name)
print(list(name1))

#result:
['l', 'a', 'w', 'j', 'a', 'r', 'p']
```

Comment: Which python version, 2 or 3?

Comment: reversed return a reversed class.you can check it by type(reversed(name))
try this.
print(*name1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

The `reversed` function returns an iterator, not a string. Iterators are special Python objects made to iterate over something (that may be more complicated than a list or a string). You can learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp).

If you want to reverse a string you can do:

```
name1 = name[::-1]
```

Comment: `reversed` is actually a class; calling it can return an instance of `reversed`, or an instance of some other type according to its argument's `__reversed__` method. In any case, that object will implement the iterator protocol, which just means it can be passed to `iter` to get an iterable object.

Comment: Probably; I can never keep "iterator" and "iterable" straight.